# I am getting below email on daily basis. How to stop it?? Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Eml Manager

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting below email on daily basis. How to stop it??
Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Eml Manager

Answer (score 0):

If you are not supposed to be running any scripts then you can just open the script editor, click on Resources → All Your triggers and then remove triggers you do not want. You can also simply disable notifications by clicking on the Notifications link to the right of the trigger and removing your e-mail.

Otherwise, in a similar manner, go to the Eml Manager and fix the code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 'Summary of failures for Google Apps Script' on daily basis, you should look forward to fixing your code because code isn't behaving as you had expected.

Here are few of the reasons which can cause those failure emails:

- Too many simultaneous invocations on the google app to which you have attached your appscript
- Authorization or Authentication issue (a new user of the script has to authorize it first time)
- Script took more than 6 minutes to complete (6 min is the limit)
- If you have created programatical triggers, and forget to delete them once it has served the purpose, it will keep on creating new triggers and there is total trigger limit per script is 20.
- In some cases, server can also be too busy to trigger your script but that rarely happens.

Also, if your script is taking too longer to complete, you should look forward to reducing the looping and also reducing writing operations on google apps(as it keeps on saving every change you made). Also, use in built formulas etc as much as possible.

If your code is totally fine according to you, then you can stop those failure emails by removing your name from the notifications option of your triggers as @Vytautas mentioned.